# Display a headline before order review table in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I am trying to add a simple headline just before the woocommerce checkout order review table. I do not want to add it with a function, but directly in the review-order.php template (I am overriding several things, so it makes sense to just override the template in my child theme). When I insert a -tag into the template, it gets displayed twice instead of just once. What do I need to change? The beginning of the review-order.php template is:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}
?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
```

and I tried:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}
?>
<h3>My headline</h3>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
```

and the headline appears twice...

How to avoid this headline appear twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this headline to appear twice use `! is_ajax()` in an `IF` statement as follow:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( ! is_ajax() ) {
    echo '<h3>'.__("My headline", "woocommerce").'</h3>';
}

?>
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
```

This time it will be displayed once, as your heading will not get ajax refreshed.